# Comparing two datetimestamp column , if that datetimestamp is present than create new row datetimestamp with default value

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, multiple-columns

I have dataframe file in which there are 9 columns , 1st column name is `adjusted_time` in which `datetime` stamp are the values but some of the `datetime` stamp values are missing. 5th column name is `daterange` in which the `datetime` stamp are in sorted and regular form ,
I want to compare 5th column `daterange` with 1st column name adjusted_time , if that particular `datetime` stamp  which is present in 9th column `daterange` is not in `adjusted_time` column than create a new row with `daterange` values and other column as 999 default value.

```
adjusted_time           longitude   latitude    hm0                 daterange
2016-01-22 00:00:00 87.65785    21.29374    60.74292        2016-01-22 00:00:00
2016-01-22 06:00:00    87.65822 21.29337    91.60878            2016-01-22 03:00:00
2016-01-22 09:00:00 87.65790    21.29302    61.00000            2016-01-22 06:00:00
2016-01-22 12:00:00 87.65768    21.29310    40.00000        2016-01-22 09:00:00
2016-01-23 00:00:00 87.65785    21.29379    48.00000        2016-01-22 12:00:00
```

As you can see that in adjusted_time column 2016-01-22 03:00:00 datetimestamp is not present , so i want a new row for 2016-01-22 03:00:00 in adjusted_time such as 
adjusted_time           longitude   latitude    hm0
2016-01-22 03:00:00 999    999    999

How i can do this with python pandas?

Comment: Let me know if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_new(df):
    for x in df['daterange']:
        if x in list(df['adjusted_time']):
           pass
        else:
           df.loc[len(df),:] = [x, 999, 999, 999, x]
    return df
```

This is not the ideal way of doing it. I tried to use lambda but can't really do assignments inside lambda. I am sure there's an efficient way of doing this.